# Is the symmetry group of the square isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_8}$? to $\mathbb{S_8}$? to a subgroup of $\mathbb{S}_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Exercise: Mark True or False. Explain why.
>
> a) The symmetry group of a square is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_8}$.
>
> b) The symmetry group of a square is isomorphic to $\mathbb{S_8}$.
>
> c)The symmetry group of a square is isomorphic to a subgroup $\mathbb{S_8}$.

I need explanation with isomorphism. I know that  symmetry group of a square is dihedral group $\mathbb{D_4}$ which has 8 elements. $\mathbb{S_8}$ means all permutations. $\mathbb{Z_8}$ cyclic group of order 8.

Comment: Is the dihedral group Abelian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_4$ is not abelian, but $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is. So they are not isomorphic.

$D_4$ has order $8$ but $S_8$ has order $8!$ and so they are not isomorphic.

$D_4$ is a permutation group of a set of cardinality $4$, so $D_4$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$, and so a subgroup of $S_8$.

Comment: Also $D_8$ is a group of order $8$, so it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$.

Comment: Exactly, by Cayley.